# Pin an item above a ScalingLazyColumn in wear OS

Tags: listview, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os

I am trying to make a page in wear os using compose where there is a list of items, you can select multiple items in the list, and then save. What I would like is to have a save button above the list so the user doesn't have to scroll to the bottom of the list to save the items they selected, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. On my page I have a ScalingLazyColumn and I've tried to add something above it and set the modifier of both to fillMaxWidth(), but the list always takes up the whole screen.

I haven't seen any possibility of adding a FAB inside compose on wear os, so I can't just have a floating button above the list for saving.

Is there a way to have an easily accessible save button so the user doesn't have to scroll to the bottom or top of the list to save their selections?
Here is the code I have for this specific page, simplified as an example...

```
@Composable
fun ReminderView() {
  val selectedList = remember {
    mutableStateListOf<String>()
  }
  val days = listOf("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
  Row( //I have tried changing this to Box also, still no luck
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
  ) {
    Button(onClick = {}) { Text("Save") }
  }
  val state = rememberScalingLazyListState()
  ScalingLazyColumn(
    state = state,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 10.dp, start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp, bottom = 40.dp),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
  ) {
    item {
      Spacer(Modifier.height(6.dp)) //added this to move the list down
    }
    for(day in days) {
      item {
        ToggleChip(
          modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(10.dp),
          checked = ...
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That does put a button on top of the screen and the list below it, because of the Spacer, but as you scroll the list it will cover the button.

Is there an easy or at least clean way to add a button to this page to allow the user to save their selections without having to either scroll to the top of the list or to the bottom of the list.

I understand in the example there are only 7 items in the list so scrolling to the top or bottom isn't that big of a deal, but if the list is longer than my example it will be ridiculous to have to scroll to the top or bottom just to save your selections.

If it matters this is in a nav host and a page that gets navigated to, so I can't really control the scaffold all that much from inside this page.

Thank you.